# File type error is bypassing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a browse file field with restricted few file formats like .ppt, .zip, .mp3 etc.
I have mention which files can get attached. My code is working my on my local but its not working when I upload my code on production. I have given my all time to fix and find the issue but I am not successful.

Here is what I have done.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function validate_fileext() {
    var check = true;
    var error_msg = "Only .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .html, .htm, .tif, .xls, .xlsx, .doc, .docx, .txt are accepted, please try again.";
        for (var j = 0; j <=upload_number; j++) {
            if (document.getElementById("attachment"+j) != null) {
                var file = document.getElementById("attachment" + j).value.toLowerCase();
               if (file != "" && !(file.lastIndexOf(".pdf") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".jpg") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".jpeg") > 0 ||                
                    file.lastIndexOf(".htm") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".html") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".tif") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".xls") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".xlsx") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".doc") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".docx") > 0 || file.lastIndexOf(".txt") > 0)) {
                    check = false;
                   document.getElementById("static_error_message").innerHTML = 'Error : Only .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .html, .htm, .tif, .xls, .xlsx, .doc, .docx, .txt are accepted as attachment(s).';
                    document.getElementById("attachment" + j).focus();
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
       return check; 
}  

function resetFileContent(){
    document.getElementById("static_attachment").innerHTML = '<div id="static_attachment" class="fieldinput"><div id="fileUpload"><input type="file" size="45" name="attachment0"  id="attachment0" onchange="document.getElementById(\'moreUploadsLink\').style.display  = \'block\'; getElementById(\'fileField\').value = getElementById(\'attachment0\').value;"" /><div id="browserVisible"><input type="text" id="fileField" /></div><div class="clr"></div><a class="link" id="link_clear" href="javascript:resetFileContent();">Clear</a> </div></div>';   
}
</script>

<form name="frm_payment" action="$field{site_url_secure}/checkout/payment.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate_fileext()">
```

Need help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the name of the file that is bypassing the validation?

Comment: I am not sure with which file it is bypassing.

Comment: Then how do you know it is not working?

Comment: when I place an alert before the function starts it shows the alert box on production. but when I am putting that alert inside the function the alert box doesn't show.
So this makes me feel that the function is bypassing or may be some other issue in the script. which is spiking my script

Comment: The validation function works fine. Perhaps the form is submitting before the validation is called. try changing the onsubmit value to `validate_fileext(); return false;`

Comment: tried but it didnt worked :(